# Yandex map JS API: HTTP-headers в запросах от LoadingObjectManager

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, header

Как-то можно передать кастомные HTTP-заголовки в запросы, которые делает LoadingObjectManager? Например заголовок Authorization

Answer (score 0):

Кастомные HTTP-заголовки в запросы, которые делает LoadingObjectManager никак не передать.